# ARC warning - "Not safe to remove an unused autorelease"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm getting the following warnings and I haven't got a clue where to start, any ideas?

```
NSObject+Be.m:36:3: [rewriter] it is not safe to remove an unused 'autorelease' message; its receiver may be destroyed immediately
NSObject+Be.m:35:40: [rewriter] NSInvocation's getReturnValue is not safe to be used with an object with ownership other than __unsafe_unretained
NSObject+Be.m:36:4: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'
```

The code came from here....
https://github.com/tylerneylon/moriarty/blob/c0d6daf65d86c22b8e5853aef00980f059c92fbc/NSObject%2BBe.m

```
#import "NSObject+Be.h"

@interface BeProxy : NSProxy {
  id target;
}

+ (BeProxy *)beProxyForClass:(Class)class;

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation;
- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector;

@end

@implementation BeProxy

+ (BeProxy *)beProxyForClass:(Class)class {
  BeProxy *beProxy = [BeProxy alloc];
  beProxy->target = [class alloc];
  return beProxy;
}
//

// We assume the method called is an init method.  The return value
// may be a new value for self.
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {
  [anInvocation setTarget:target];
  [anInvocation invoke];
  id object;
  [anInvocation getReturnValue:(void *)&object];   //HERE
  [object autorelease];                            //HERE
  [self release];
}

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
  return [target methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
}

@end

//    


@implementation NSObject (Be)

+ (id)be {
  return [BeProxy beProxyForClass:[self class]];
}

+ (id)beInit {
  return [[[self class] new] autorelease];
}

- (id)beCopy {
  return [[self copy] autorelease];
}

@end
```

Comment: That project is not meant to be used within an ARC environment as it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation:

> NSObject+Be This category is designed to help with memory management.
>   Specifically, this makes it easy to only work with autoreleased
>   objects outside of a small number of ownership-allowed methods.

So the posted code is to help with manual retain count memory management. Don't compile it with ARC, then.

Comment: Curious on why this was down voted - yes, the wording might not be exactly right as "manual retain count" is not what "autorelease" does but overall that answer seems to be exactly hitting the spot.

Comment: @Till "Manual retain count" or MRC seems to be the established name for non-ARC memory management under Objective-C.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Pre-ARC is typically written as "MRR" or Manual Retain-Release.

Comment: @pkamb I've seen "Manual Reference Counting" a lot (i.e. in Apple's ARC transitioning guide).